# Build OpenGrok source failed

Tags: java, ant, opengrok

I want to build OpenGrok from source following this link (https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/wiki/How-to-build-OpenGrok-from-source). When I use ant command to build the OpenGrok, I met the following errors:

```
BUILD FAILED
/tmp/hxu2/OpenGrok/nbproject/build-impl.xml:415: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/tmp/hxu2/OpenGrok/nbproject/build-impl.xml:201: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1174)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Anybody can give me a hand?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your javac is from jdk7 installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My JDK version is too low, then I updated it, problem solved!